# Ie8 not rendering embedded fonts to dynamic divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face, embedded-fonts

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "England Hand";
    src:  url("fonts/englandhand.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("fonts/englandhand.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have the above as the font style. Its included in the body of the page. I have not added the font family to a div and it renders there ohk. When I create a clone of this div and assign it another position and id, the font stops rendering.

There is also no error in the console. This error only occurs on IE 8 and works fine on IE 9 .

**SOLUTION**
Look out for js errors. Surely there will be one in there leading to the issue

Comment: CSS styles shouldn't really be declared inside the BODY tag. Best practice is to link to an external stylesheet in your HEAD tag or place your CSS with a STYLE tag in the HEAD of the page.

Comment: Yup I know that but on some question here i read that this helps IE8 to render correctly. Well I am trying to do all that i can.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing some prefixes for the ie8/ie9 support. Your code needs to look something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'deutsch_gothicnormal';
    src: url('deutsch-webfont.eot');
    src: url('deutsch-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('deutsch-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('deutsch-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('deutsch-webfont.svg#deutsch_gothicnormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: src: url('deutsch-webfont.eot'); is the code for ie9 support. while the nect line defines that foe ie8 so for ie8 my @font-face is correct.